# Request handler is executed, but response status is always 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request, http-status-code-404

I have a simple web controller that handles requests to `GET /base/{userId}/test/{userId}` (e.g. `GET /base/1/test/2`) and returns an object that should be converted to JSON later.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/base/{userId}")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/test/{testId}")
    Response<TestDto> getTest(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, @PathVariable("testId") Long testId) {
        return Response.ok(testService.get(userId));
    }

}
```

But whenever I call it I get "404 - Not found" in response. I've debugged my code and I'm sure that the `TestService` service and the `Response#ok()` method are working fine.

Then I've debugged Spring Framework sources and found that for some unknown bizarre reason the Spring's internal **filter chain is executed twice** and request URI is messed up in the second execution (URI is duplicated). E.g., on the first execution I have `request.servletPath = "/base/1/test/2"`, on the subsequent execution I have `request.servletPath = "/base/1/base/1/test/2"` *(* see notes below)*. Then the mentioned 404 error is returned, cause apparently I don't have mapping for `/base/1/base/1/test/2` in my application.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

---

* `request` is of type `ApplicationHttpRequest` here.
   Other messed up request properties are: `strippedServletPath`, `requestDispatcherPath`, `requestUri`. I don't put them in the answer body for a sake of brevity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to put [`@ResponseBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) annotation on your `getTest()` method.

> Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body.

This code should work:

```
@GetMapping("/test/{testId}")
@ResponseBody
public Response<TestDto> getTest(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, @PathVariable("testId") Long testId) {
    return Response.ok(testService.get(userId));
}
```